# Radio button not checked by default in jqxTreeGrid

Tags: jqxwidgets

I am trying to implement `rowDetails` functionality of jqxTreeGrid, my `rowDetailsRenderer` function returns something like :

`return '<input type="radio" name="group1" checked="checked">';`

Its not showing as checked. Event after the grid is loaded, I am not able to 'check' it through firebug as well. But its getting checked once I click it. Same behavior across firefox/IE/Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your checkbox inside a `table`

View this example: [JqxTreeGrid rowdetail with checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/66ykpL69/)

Comment: For checkox it was working earlier as well. Tried your fiddle for multiple radios in one rowdetail, and its working thanks! Any idea why it doesn't work if we dont return a table and return just radio button like i was doing earlier?

Comment: May be we use an old jqx lib. Now, your code can work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/uqtwy30f/

Comment: @RongNguyen - Can you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/g_arora/6wLw8c8t/ I would like to check all the child-nodes while checked parent

Comment: @GauravKumarArora I am sorry. JqxTreeGrid does not support by default, you can try my suggestion to solve this issue, it require some efforts so try by yourself :-) Link: http://jsfiddle.net/h8t1oem4/